# Reply-to field is not visible on new mailing

Tags: civimail

It is not possible to select reply-to on new mailing screen

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a known issue with the bootstrap theme reported at https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/628

We were able to fix it by adding the following CSS into our theme css or custom civicrm css

```
.form-group .select2-container.ng-not-empty a {
  min-height:30px;
}
```